# When I choose to use one of the following scenarios?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm starting in DDD and I have encountered this image:

[DDD Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93wnn.png)

I'd like to know when I choose to use one of the following scenarios:

1º - UI -> Application -> Domain -> Infra

2º - UI -> Application -> Infra

3º - UI -> Domain

4º - UI -> Infra

If anyone can help me, thank you immensely.

Comment: Do you need an answer specific to C#?

Comment: @WilsonSantos This is the Layered Architecture pattern from the original DDD book. It is less popular these days. For newer alternatives, see Hexagonal Architecture and Onion Architecture. The questions you ask probably don't make sense in a typical 2017 DDD setting.

Comment: @guillaume31 In practice the layered architecture with DIP applied is pretty much the same as the Hexagonal architecture. You can just replace `infrastructure` by `port & adapters` and the implementation is the same, no?

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @plalx P&A would replace the UI layer as well then... you end up with a very different schema. I'm also not sure if a port can reference another port directly *(UI => Infra)*. Plus, recent versions of Hexagonal have a Domain core inside the Application hexagon, which rules out *UI => Domain*.

Comment: DIP also introduces a difference between compile-time dependencies and runtime dependencies which doesn't appear on this schema. `Question 1°` is very different if interpreted litterally (Domain has a compile-time reference to Infra) or specifying that there's a DI level of indirection between Domain and Infra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image I see that you are referring to the old **Layered architecture**, in its relaxed form (top layers are allowed to depend only on bottom layers, on any inferior level).

I will give you language agnostic examples for every scenario:

**1º - UI -> Application -> Domain -> Infra**

This is the most common scenario: user submit a form to create a new entity from the `UI`; then the `UI` gathers the data from the form and calls an `Application` service that creates a new entity object (with the new operator or using a factory), and the entity constructor (which resides in the `Domain` layer) initializes the entity; then the `Application` service use the repositories from the `Infrastructure` (for example a SQL Repository) to persist the newly created entity.

**2º - UI -> Application -> Infra**

This could be the scenario when the `UI` checks if the current user has the right to access a resource using an `Application` service that read some file from the disk using `Infrastructure`; security is an `Application` layer responsibility.

**3º - UI -> Domain**

The `UI` calls a `Domain` service to perform some calculation; for example, the VAT calculation on some product price in order to display to user

**4º - UI -> Infra**

The `UI` want to show the admin user the status of the Database connection (which is in the `Infrastructure` layer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.